# Storm Trident Window Join

Tags: join, window, state, apache-storm, trident

I've implemented window joining in my storm trident topology using a partitionPersist stage and a state query. I would like to remove items from my in memory state as I'm querying. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation it seems as though the state updates and queries are in order. So it's safe to update the state while querying it. Will monitor this though.